# a Radon measure is determined by a linear functional on the space of continuous functions with compact support

Tags: measure-theory

Where can I read a proof of the following statement (if it is true).

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space (not necessarily locally compact) and let $\mu$ be a Radon (i.e. locally finite and inner regular) measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$. The measure $\mu$ is determined by the functional $\phi\mapsto\int_{X} \phi d\mu, \phi\in C_{c}(X)$.

I have definitely seen the locally compact case before but I am not sure about the general case. It may be that the proof is really easy.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159853/rieszs-representation-theorem-for-non-locally-compact-spaces

But it looks like they're unable to find proofs without some replacement for local compactness.  I doubt that the statement is true in the generality you've stated, but I can't find support for that.

Comment: Ah.  Try the fourth paragraph here: http://www.drmaciver.com/2014/04/locally-compact-hausdorff/

Without local compactness or a similar assumption, you can't fully recover $\mu$ by the argument there.